# Link Open Source Google Code Project with own Open Source Project in Git Hub

Tags: github, google-code

I am setting up an open source project on Github and want to make use of a GPL v3 project residing in Google Code repo.

How would I do that? Checkout the Google Code repo and make it (unmodified) available in my repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Don't do that. Simply document it as a dependency, optionally offer automatic downloading and building in your build system, and that's it. If you include third-party libraries in your distribution, [most](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging%3aNo_Bundled_Libraries) [Linux](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-embeddedfiles) [distributions](http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE%3aPackaging_guidelines#Duplication_of_system_libraries) [are](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Packaging_Standards) going to hate you.